# How to serve html in express.js that references js file from server and run it on client side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to write simplest possible server that serves html page with client side scripts.

Already tried based on http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html, 
[Using express.js to serve html file along with scripts, css, and images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504798/using-express-js-to-serve-html-file-along-with-scripts-css-and-images/31505061) and
[How to load JS file in html using express server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019453/how-to-load-js-file-in-html-using-express-server), but still I don't get it.

File structure I'm using:

```
node_modules
resources
resources/page.html
resources/script.js
index.js
package.json
```

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname , 'resources', 'page.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Content
  </body>
  <script scr="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var i = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  if (i < 10) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
  }
}, 100);
```

I type in google chrome browser address `localhost:3000/` and page is successfully loader ("Content" string is displayed), but script `script.js` is not running (empty console). I expect browser to retrieve script.js file and print numbers to console when page.html is loaded.

Comment: Do you get anything at `localhost:3000/script.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `page.html` file, change the property `scr` to `src` in the script tag and it will work.

Comment: OMG, I'm a freaking moron, lost 2 hours of lifetime for that. Thanks a lot - works